# Image increasing kb on resize

Tags: images, compression

I'm trying to compress an image on upload, but it turns out that wordpress is creating 7 more copies of the image and one of the its more large in kb than the original one. (original has 15kb, resized has 90kb)

I was wondering what could be causing this.

Current using Compress PNG to WP plugin to compress the images. (https://wordpress.org/plugins/compress-png-for-wp/)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure how we can help you. Is your issue happening also without the plugin? If it only happen with the plugin you should ask to the plugin developer.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I did some tests, and its not the plugin, its wordpress that's increasing the filesize of the image, on the resize.

Comment: Are you experience the issue with all images you upload?

Comment: Not all images, but with almost all png's that I upload.

Comment: Just found out that only increases the filesize of the image when wordpress crops the image to a custom size.

Comment: I think that is not a problem specific to WordPress. I can see this issue some times even working with PhotoShop. It depends on several factors from the original image and the manipulation done to the image. I think there is nothing we can do in WordPress context. Anyway, for optimizing images in WodPress I've had a very good experience with EWWW Image Optimizer, if you want to try. You can also check the configuration of Imagick or GD Library in your server (WordPress use that libraries for image manipulation), not sure if this configuration can modified directly from WP_Image_Editor class.

Comment: Have you had any luck with this?